# Not Triggering OnClick Event IE8 but Works Fine In Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

```
  var hyp = document.createElement("a");
  //hyp.style.cssText='cursor:pointer';
  hyp.onclick="RemoveDv('" + divid + "');";    
  hyp.innerHTML = "Remove";
```

I have javascript with this code snippit in there. In firefox everything works fine but in IE8 it works fine if I run it locally, but uploading the code to a server and running through my same IE8 browser that I ran it locally the RemoveDv event will NOT fire.

This is the html created from this javascript

```
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="RemoveDv('dv1');">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onclick` should be a function, not a string.

```
hyp.onclick = function() {RemoveDv(divid);};
```

EDIT: Hey, this is my 2,000th answer!

Comment: Adding that to the code does not create an onclick event in IE if I look at what has been created in ie developer tools I can see that no onclick is being added to the hyperlink <a style="">

Comment: That's because you're working with the `onclick` *property*, not the `onClick` *attribute*. There's a difference. To illustrate this difference, try this: `<input type="text" value="blah blah" />`. Then, change the contents of the textbox and check the `value` attribute in the IE tools. You will see that the attribute hasn't changed, even though the property has.